# input auto calculation with change event

Tags: jquery

Hallo iam new at coding and iam trying to make a points system with JQuery. What iam trying to do is to make it automatically calculate the points every time you put in a new number.

My id="score" start at 10 and i can add points to it from id="addToScore" but every time i put in a new number it just add to the current value and i want it to show the new result.

My bonus start at 0 and every time you get 2 point from my score, from 10 you will get 1 bonus point. But every time i add point from the id="addToScore" it will not update my bonus point.

And my id="addToBonus" also add to the current value to id="bonus" when i only want it to show the new result in the id="bonus".

I hope that someone will help me out with what iam doing wrong and iam thinking that it maybe is this change() event.

```
    <input type="text" value="10" placeholder="My Score" id="score">
    <input type="text" placeholder="Bonus Points" id="bonus">

    <input type="text" placeholder="add To Score" id="addToScore">
    <input type="text" placeholder="add To Bonus" id="addToBonus">


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.0/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>

    $(document).on("change","input",function(){
        var getScore = Number($("#score").val());
        var getBonus = Number($("#bonus").val());
        var getAddToScore = Number($("#addToScore").val());
        var getAddToBonus = Number($("#addToBonus").val());
        CalculateBonus = Math.floor((getScore-10)/2);
        $("#bonus").val(CalculateBonus);
        var addToTheScore = getScore + getAddToScore;
        var addToTheBonus = getBonus + getAddToBonus;
        $("#score").val(addToTheScore);
        $("#bonus").val(addToTheBonus);
    });
</script>
```

Comment: try to use updated CDN of jQuery.

Comment: check: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/urLp9bbd/) and changes. i set the score readonly and don't calculate when try to change score.

Answer (score 0):

try [keyup()](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/)

```js
$('input').keyup(function(){
  var getScore = Number($("#score").val());
  var getBonus = Number($("#bonus").val());
  var getAddToScore = Number($("#addToScore").val());
  var getAddToBonus = Number($("#addToBonus").val());
  CalculateBonus = Math.floor((getScore - 10) / 2);
  $("#bonus").val(CalculateBonus);
  var addToTheScore = getScore + getAddToScore;
  var addToTheBonus = getBonus + getAddToBonus;
  $("#score").val(addToTheScore);
  $("#bonus").val(addToTheBonus);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" value="10" placeholder="My Score" id="score">
<input type="text" placeholder="Bonus Points" id="bonus">

<input type="text" placeholder="add To Score" id="addToScore">
<input type="text" placeholder="add To Bonus" id="addToBonus">
```

Comment: you forgot to mention about the changing of CDN.

Comment: sorry ? i didnt understand what do you mean by changing CDN ?

Comment: you use version 2.1.1 and the question has 1.12.0

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use the change event in all input fields. Instead you should use on specific input fields by using their id.

like this

$(document).on("change","#addToScore, #addToBonus",function(){
....
}

Also one you have calculated, at the end of that function block you have the clear the values of the text fields #addToScore and #addToBonus by doing this

$("#addToBonus").val("");
$("#addToScore").val("");